# Forwarding a c:set value to a new JSP page

Tags: jsp, internationalization

I am implementing i18n in a jsp tutorial but am having trouble forwarding the stored locale onto new pages. I set the locale with the following code:

```
<c:set var="theLocale" value="${not empty param.theLocale ? param.theLocale : session.theLocale}"scope="session" />
```

However when I click a link to a new jsp the variable is not forwarded across. I have the following code to detect the variable in the target jsp:

```
<c:set var="theLocale" value="${not empty param.theLocale ? param.theLocale : pageContext.request.locale}"scope="session" />
```

I thought that as its a session variable it would get passed in the request. Do I explicitly need to add it?

Comment: It doesn't need to be forwarded. It is  simply stored in scope. Did you try using exactly what you used in the first page in the second page?

Comment: You could use the <c:out> tag in second page. Actually, you could just use EL by itself   ${not empty param.theLocale ? param.theLocale : session.theLocale}